# Angular Autocomplete Error Messages (without floating label)

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I'm looking to add validation error messages for an Angular Autocomplete component.  I followed an example I found in [How to add validation attributes to md-autocomplete angular material directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29262322/how-to-add-validation-attributes-to-md-autocomplete-angular-material-directive), but I do not want to use a floating label.  How can I achieve this?  Here's my HTML:

```html
<md-autocomplete md-input-id="person"
                 md-input-name="person"
                 md-item-text="item.displayName"
                 md-items="item in getPeople(searchText)"
                 md-search-text="searchText"
                 md-selected-item="model.person"
                 md-selected-item-change="form.person.$setValidity('itemInList', !!item)"
                 md-min-length="0"
                 placeholder="Enter a person"
                 md-select-on-focus
                 class="output"
                 required>
    <md-item-template>
        <span class="md-item" md-highlight-text="searchText" md-highlight-flags="^i">{{item.displayName}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
    <md-not-found>
        <span class="md-item">No matches found.</span>
    </md-not-found>
</md-autocomplete>
<div ng-messages="form.allowWrite.$error" ng-if="form.allowWrite.$touched" class="help-block">
    <div ng-message="required">Person is required</div>
    <div ng-message="itemInList">Person was not selected from the list</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that adding the "md-no-float" attribute fixed my problem.  Here's an updated snippet:

```html
    <md-autocomplete md-input-id="person"
                     md-input-name="person"
                     md-item-text="item.displayName"
                     md-items="item in getPeople(searchText)"
                     md-search-text="searchText"
                     md-selected-item="model.person"
                     md-selected-item-change="form.person.$setValidity('itemInList', !!item)"
                     md-min-length="0"
                     placeholder="Enter a person"
                     md-select-on-focus
                     class="output"
      md-no-float
                     required>
```